# Source command for those lines in file which doesn't have equal to(=)

Tags: bash, shell-script, awk, sed

I have a file like this:

```
(blank line)
[Test1]
a=1
b=2
c=3
```

I have to read value of `a`,`b`,`c` in variables, so I used `source` command and it did the job. But for the line 2 i.e. `[Test1]`, it show command not found.

How can I take `[Test1]` in a variable too?

Basically I am expecting:

```
$some_var=[Test1]
$a=1
$b=2
$c=3
```

So I can use these values further.

Currently what I am doing is removing first two lines from the file and then `source file`, and by doing this I am not getting line 2 in a variable. I am looking for a better way. I am doing it all inside a bash script.

Comment: What sort of format *is* your source file?  Is that a standard format of some sort, perhaps an INI file?  Is whitespace allowed in the source file variable values?  How about between the `=` and the value?  Are quotes allowed in the source file?

Comment: File looks like same as given in question. Yes it is an ini file. No quotes are not allowed.

Comment: Do you only want the variables specified under a particular heading in the INI file, or do you want *all* variables?  (In most INI files I have seen, each separate heading may reuse the same variable name with a different associated value.  Would you want to just let the final definition clobber any previous values?)

Comment: In this there is only one heading.. and first line is blank. I want that heading in one variable and variables specified under that heading.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use a [ini file parser](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6318901/4207561) to parse your file. Even though it may be a bit [overkill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overkill_(term)), it should do the job

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have process substitution, you can do something like this:

```
source <(sed 's/^\[/some_var=\[/' file)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the files are not big (since bash 4.4):

```
readarray -t arr <infile         # the value in zero is a blank line.
some_var="${arr[1]}"             # use the first line.
. <(printf '%s\n' "${arr[@]:2}") # source the rest.
echo "some_var=$some_var a=$a a=$b a=$c"
```

When executed:

```
$ ./script
some_var=[Test1] a=1 a=2 a=3
```

For older bash, the solution becomes much more convoluted, but possible.
This is the equivalent since bash 2.04 (2000-03-21).

```
unset arr; i=0
while IFS='' read -r a ; do arr[i]="$a"; ((i++));done <infile
some_var="${arr[1]}"                    # use the first line.
. <(printf '%s\n' "${arr[@]:2}")        # source the rest.
```

Comment: `readarray: command not found`, this is what I am getting when I execute this in my bash script.

Comment: @serenesat Added solution for (very) old bash versions, since 2.04. Please try again.

Comment: When I echo $some_var, I get the desire output but echoing $a, $b or $c, it is not showing anything. How to achieve that?

Comment: @serenesat The code as written works for me here. I added some detail on the first script (copy to the second) and try. If it still fails, please provide a run with `bash -x ./script` to debug.